# Pandas XML: How to read this file?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I read in XML data that looks like this into Pandas? The code executes, but contains no information:

```
import pandas as pd

xml1 = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory SchemaVersion="1.0" ItemID="TestItem">
  <SpecificDeviceGroup>
    <Device Count="2" Description="Base System Device">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
    <Device Count="1" Description="PCI Express" Class="System">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere2" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
</SpecificDeviceGroup>
</Inventory>
'''

pd.read_xml(xml1)  # no data
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I am not quite sure what the expected output would be in the case of XML. I am assuming we would get columns with some values (vice an empty DF). Massaging could be done from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `read_xml` takes the first nested version as the dataframe data. See also the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html).
In your case that is the within the `<Inventory>` tag, but that contains no list of data. You can specify where to start using `xpath` within `read_xml`.

The following code gets me a short DataFrame, with columns count, Description, HardWareIDs, Class.

```
import pandas as pd

xml1 = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory SchemaVersion="1.0" ItemID="TestItem">
  <SpecificDeviceGroup>
    <Device Count="2" Description="Base System Device">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
    <Device Count="1" Description="PCI Express" Class="System">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere2" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
</SpecificDeviceGroup>
</Inventory>
'''

pd.read_xml(xml1, xpath = ".//Device")
```